# how to use i18n to gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, i18next

I have a problem with translations in my gatsby site.

I am using the i18n plugin to make translations but if i put in my `index.jsx` two FormattedMessage tag, it breaks my `index.jsx`.

I can find my issue in google but i can't figure out how to resolve it.

My index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'

import Layout from '../components/Layout'


const IndexPage = ({ pathContext: { locale } }) => (
  <Layout locale={locale}>
    <FormattedMessage id="hello" />
    <FormattedMessage id="hello" />
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

and my layout:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

import Header from './header'
import './layout.css'

import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData } from 'react-intl'

// Locale data
import enData from 'react-intl/locale-data/en'
import ptData from 'react-intl/locale-data/pt'
import esData from 'react-intl/locale-data/es'

// Messages
import en from '../i18n/en.json'
import pt from '../i18n/pt.json'
import es from '../i18n/es.json'

const messages = { en, pt, es }

addLocaleData([...enData, ...ptData, ...esData])

const Layout = ({ locale, children }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <>
        <Helmet
          title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
          meta={[
            { name: 'description', content: 'Sample' },
            { name: 'keywords', content: 'sample, something' },
          ]}
        >
          <html lang="en" />
        </Helmet>
        <Header lang="/^\/eng/" />
        <div
          style={{
            margin: '0 auto',
            maxWidth: 960,
            padding: '0px 1.0875rem 1.45rem',
            paddingTop: 0,
          }}
        >
          <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages[locale]}>
            {children}
          </IntlProvider>
        </div>
      </>
    )}
  />
)

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

I hope you can't help me to use more than one FormattedMessage tag for translations, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe is not a valid solution for you but. Did you try [gatsby-plugin-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-i18next)? My first project with gatsbyjs was a nightmare deal with languages until I found it. In my opinion, it works really well. You must install it with npm/yarn and configure a little bit. You can remove the wrapper `IntlProvider` and you can take translations wherever you want (pages/templates or components).

Here and example extracted from your code (English & Spanish languages). The plugin take care of the URL, putting `/es` & `/en` in every `pages/templates`:

**src/pages/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { I18n } from 'react-i18next'; 
import { withI18next } from 'gatsby-plugin-i18next';
import Layout from '../components/index'

const IndexPage = props => (<I18n>{t => (
    <Layout{...props}>
        <p>{t('hello')}</p>
        <p>{t('hello')}</p>
    </Layout>
)}</I18n>);

export const query = graphql`
query($lng: String!){
    locales: allLocale(filter: { lng: { eq:$lng }, ns: { eq: "messages" } }) {
      ...TranslationFragment
    }
  }
`;

export default withI18next()(IndexPage);
```

**src/components/index.jsx**

Note that you must change Helmet as well. I translate the metadata in order to show how can translate in components (not pages neither templates).

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import { Head } from 'gatsby-plugin-i18next';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

import Header from './header'
import './layout.css'

const Layout = ({children, t }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <>
        <Head hreflang>
           <title>{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</title>
           <meta name="description" content="{t('metaDescription')}" />
           <meta name="keywords" content="{t('metaKeywords')}" />
        </Head>
        <Header lang="/^\/eng/" />
        <div
          style={{
            margin: '0 auto',
            maxWidth: 960,
            padding: '0px 1.0875rem 1.45rem',
            paddingTop: 0,
          }}
        >
        {children}
        </div>
      </>
    )}
  />
)

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default translate()(Layout)
```

**gatsby-config.js**
You can debug the plugin only when you are developing ;)

```
const defaultLanguage = "en";
const languages: ["en", "es"];
const siteUrl: "https://domain-where-the-gatsby-are-published.com/",

module.exports = {
    ...,
    plugins: [
        ...,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-i18next`,
            options: {
                availableLngs: languages,
                fallbackLng: defaultLanguage,
                debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                siteUrl
            },
        }
    ],
}
```

**locale/en/messages.json**

```
{
  "hello": "Hi!",
  "metaDescription": "Sample page with i18n translations",
  "metaKeywords": "i18n, gatsbyjs, english"
}
```

**locale/es/messages.json**

```
{
  "hello": "Hola!",
  "metaDescription": "Página de ejemplo con traducciones i18n",
  "metaKeywords": "i18n, gatsbyjs, spanish"
}
```

As an extra comment:

- Remember to change all the links imported from `gatsby` to
  `gatsby-plugin-i18next`
- You must inject the `graphql` query in every `pages/templates`
- You can see the code of the [starter](https://github.com/ikhudo/gatsby-i18n-plugin/tree/master/starters/gatsby-starter-i18next) to see how can you create a switcher between the languages